# how do I make this class reuseable in typescript? meta programming? subclasses? injected module?

Tags: javascript, typescript, metaprogramming, typescript2.0

I've got this EventsStorage typescript class that is responsible for storing and retrieving Event objects in ionic-storage (wrapper for sqlite and indexedDB).  It uses my Event class throughout.

I would like to reuse a lot of this logic for something other than an Event, like a Widget.

I come from a ruby background where it would be relatively simple to extract all the storage logic, set a ruby var that is literally the class Event and use that var wherever I use Event.  Can I do something similar in typescript?  Is there another mechanic I can use to reuse the bulk of this class for something else, like Widget?

Ideally, my EventsStorage class becomes really lightweight, and I'm not just wrapping calls to `this.some_storage_module.get_ids()` or `this.some_storage_module.insert_new_objs()` -- which would have to be copy/pasted to every other instance I needed this.

Something like this:

```
export class EventsStorage {  // extends BaseStorage (maybe??)
  constructor(){
    super(Event, 'events'); // or some small set of magical args
  }
}
```

Here's the existing class:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage }    from '@ionic/storage';

import { Event }      from '../classes/event';

// EventsStorage < EntityStorage
// - tracks local storage info
// - a key to an array of saved objects
// - a query() method that returns saved objects

@Injectable()
export class EventsStorage {
  base_key: string;
  ids_key: string;

  constructor(
    private storage: Storage
  ){
    this.base_key = 'event';
    this.ids_key = [this.base_key, 'ids'].join('_');
  }

  get_ids(): Promise<any>{
    return this.storage.ready().then(() => {
      return this.storage.get(this.ids_key).then((val) => {
        if(val === null){
          return [];
        } else {
          return val;
        }
      });
    });
  }

  insert_new_objs(new_objs: any): Promise<any>{
    return new_objs.reduce((prev: Promise<string>, cur: any): Promise<any> => {
      return prev.then(() => {
        return this.storage.set(cur._id, cur.event);
      });
    }, Promise.resolve()).then(() => {
      console.log('saving event_ids');
      return this.storage.set(this.ids_key, new_objs.map(obj => obj._id));
    });
  }

  update(events: Event[]): Promise<any> {
    let new_objs = events.map((event) => {
      return {
        _id: [this.base_key, event.id].join('_'),
        event: event
      };
    });

    return this.insert_new_objs(new_objs);
  }

  query(): Promise<Event[]>{
    let events = [];
    return this.get_ids().then((ids) => {
      return ids.reduce((prev: Promise<string>, cur: string): Promise<any> => {
        return prev.then(() => {
          return this.get_id(cur).then((raw_event) => {
            events = events.concat([raw_event as Event]);
            return events;
          });
        });
      }, Promise.resolve());
    });
  }

  get_id(id: string): Promise<Event>{
    return this.storage.get(id).then((raw_event) => {
      return raw_event;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: You can extend classes like you stated in your comment in the first code block: `class EventsStorage extends EntityStorage`, see also: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Comment: Yea, aware of that, but it seems there's a lot more that goes into making this code reuseable than just... extends FooBaseClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you want to use generics. You basically define some basic interface between all the things you'll want to store, and your code should depend on that interface. In your code as far as I can tell you only use the `id` property.

So it would look kinda like this

```
import { Event }  from '...';
import { Widget } from '...';
interface HasId{
    id: string;
}

class ItemsStorage<T extends HasId> {
 ....
 get_id(id: string): Promise<T>{
    ...
 }
}

const EventStorage = new ItemsStorage<Events>(storage);
const WidgetStorage = new ItemsStorage<Widget>(storage);
const ev = EventStorage.get_id('abc');     //type is Promise<Event>
const wd = WidgetStorage.get_id('def');    //type is Promise<Widget>
```

You can read more about generics [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).

Edit: 
1 - about subclassing - It's usually less preferable. If your ItemsStorage class need different behavior when dealing with Events vs Widgets, than subclassing is your solution. But if you have the same behavior for every class, one might call your code *generic*, and using generics is better.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure that it's 'id' that is shared between these things.  These classes don't represent an instance of a Widget or Event, they save and retrieve blobs of data from the DB.  So, I think it's storage which is the one thing that needs to be instantiated in the superclass or generic. Also, in your example 'storage' seems to be undefined?

Comment: I figure this was pretty close. Generics were helpful